# URL re write doesn't work when some query string vars are empty

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I have the following rule rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule dest/(.*)/item/(.*)/aId/(.*)/tId/(.*)/? rss.php?dest=$1&item=$2&aId=$3&bId=$4 [NC,L]
```

This produces the following URL
http://domain.com/dest/NYC/item/coke/aId/1234/bId/asdbg

But if aId and tId are missing, it throws a 404 error:
http://domain.com/dest/NYC/item/coke

Please can someone help me figure out why? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `/dest/NYC/item/coke` won't match the regular expression `dest/(.*)/item/(.*)/aId/(.*)/tId/(.*)/?`, thus the clean SEO friendly URL isn't rewritten for rss.php to handle, and I'm going to assume you don't have a directory tree in your document root that looks like "/dest/NYC/item/coke", thus the 404. You'll need to modify the rules a little to accommodate for the missing parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^dest/(.*)/item/(.*)/aId/(.*)/tId/(.*)/?$ rss.php?dest=$1&item=$2&aId=$3&bId=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^dest/(.*)/item/(.*)/?$ rss.php?dest=$1&item=$2 [NC,L]
```

The second rule will handle the case when the **aId** and **tId** are missing from the clean URL.